# RedirectToAction in static method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Maybe i'm having just a brain meltdown ..

but i had this static method (in a static class) 
and the ideia was to redirectoaction(s).  when called.

```
    public static class ControllerHelpers
{
    public static ActionResult RedirectToLogon(HttpContext ctx) 
    {
        try
        {
            return View(@"Account\LogOn.aspx", new { ReturnUrl = ctx.Request.RawUrl });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally 
        {
            ctx = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone help on this? 
I keep having this:
"The name 'View' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: That's correct, it doesn't.  View is a member function.  A static function cannot call a Member function.  Member functions need an instance of a class.  Besides, that's not a redirect anyways, returning a view just displays the template you passed, it doesn't cause a redirect which requires a 301 or 302 return code status.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a redirect.  What you want is something like this, which is an actual 301 redirect which will cause the URL to change in the browser:

```
public static class ControllerHelpers
{
    public static ActionResult RedirectToLogon(HttpContext ctx) 
    {
        try
        {
            return new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                   new { 
                       action = "LogOn", 
                       controller = "Account", 
                       ReturnUrl = ctx.Request.RawUrl }));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally 
        {
            ctx = null; // Why on earth do you want to do this????
        }
    }
}
```